# EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/sentry-cli'

Tags: node.js, npm, nuxt.js, sentry

System: Ubuntu 20.04
NodeJs Version: v14.17.5
NPM Version: 7.20.6
Command used: sudo npm i @nuxtjs/sentry

I'm trying to install [@nuxtjs/sentry](https://sentry.nuxtjs.org/) and getting this message:

> code 1
> npm ERR! command failed
> npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/install.js
> npm ERR! info sentry-cli Downloading from https://downloads.sentry-cdn.com/sentry-cli/1.68.0/sentry-cli-Linux-x86_64
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/sentry-cli'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-08-21T09_51_43_400Z-debug.log

Comment: You should not install npm scripts with `sudo`. Try without it.

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, you could maybe also try `yarn add @nuxtjs/sentry`.

Comment: yarn solved the issue. Thank you sir

Comment: Are you using `yarn` tho or `npm` for your project?

Comment: I'm using `npm`, but it's not matter just solved :), Thank you bro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `yarn add @nuxtjs/sentry` is apparently enough and solves OP's issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar error when running my Nuxt app in docker. Says `npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/sentry-cli'`. Using `npm install @nuxtjs/sentry`. Actually, all the packages are being installed using npm only.